# Improve speed Sharepoint request via meta-data

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

To avoid the XY-problem / confusion I'm talking first my problem and then how I would like to solve it:

Currently I am building an application to retrieve Sharepoint files. The first version of the application is retrieving the URL (I know the url with the given input) and downloading the stream, which was pretty fast!
Unfortunately, to have multiple versions of sharepoint files, we have to rename the file-names to timestamps and the program has to search through the meta-data. When I have the file found, I know the URL and thus the stream for download.

So far so good, I have a working example and I DO get a stream back. But the problem is that it takes 44 seconds to complete.
The problem is in the:

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The following CAML query is used:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Shipment' />
                    <Value Type='Number'>766956</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Loadunit' />
                    <Value Type='Number'>389254</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Doc_type' />
                <Value Type='Text'>POD</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

*I formatted this block of query with tabs etc. for a better readability. As I mentioned: the query works, no errors.*

The Sharepoint (2013) library has an amount of 50 000 items (and increasing everyday).
The column-tables "Shipment" and "LoadUnit" are indexed. I re-indexed the whole thing in the weekend, but with no luck.

Also I've followed some tips, but many of them where already done or don't have to:

- http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2010/03/18/how-to-avoid-the-top-5-sharepoint-performance-mistakes/
- http://www.networkworld.com/article/2210265/tech-primers/10-steps-to-optimize-sharepoint-performance.html

My final solution is to get back to my first idea for searching on the URL without the meta-data part and without the timestamps as name / URL. But it would be nice / more organised to have it with the metadata.

*PS: For the curious ones: I'm working in the transport industry. We have to save legal files for the customer, therefore I am building an application where it automatically gives it to whoever it asks.*

Comment: I see that you're using the client object model, but do you know whether your SharePoint instance is on premises or cloud-hosted? If it's on-prem, you'll have some server-side development options available that can speed things up.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Sharepoint is on-prem, but this program will be hosted on another server and I can't use the server-side libraries due the licenses.
I am trying the REST-API for searching on meta-data and will keep this thread up to date with my findings..

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you should minimize the amount of data you are retrieving from any database/system, especially when the latency between the target and the source is high. In a CAML query you can do that by explicitly defining the list of the fields you want in the [ViewFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx) property of the SPQuery object.

There is a [long list of best practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx) you can follow for a high performance list/library in SharePoint. However, since the data you are dealing with is of legal nature, I am assuming that it is highly secured and that might be root cause of the performance issues you are having. If there is a high number of uniquely secured items in a SharePoint list, any operation on that list will take a huge performance hit. If that's the case for your target list, redesign it. Start by consolidating related items into folders as much as possible and secure the folders instead of individual documents. Then make sure to read the row-wrapping and lookup fields sections of the article linked above. Indeed, if you are going to be involved with SharePoint for a while, memorize every single principle in that article and live by it... You will start enjoying your job a lot more, your mood will improve and overall you will become a happier person, I promise...

Comment: I already love my job, my mood is good and I'm already happy with the my life, but thanks anyway..
About the data that I am retrieving: this will be normally 1 item, but can take up to saying roughly 10 items/results. The data of 1 item isn't that much except for the file that is roughly 1MB (megabyte).
You have to login to get the file(s), which I am doing correctly. Accessing the file via the URL is pretty fast, so there is no delays for Sharepoint itself.
My attempt to get the files right now is through the built-in REST-api. I keep this thread up to date with my findings. Thank you.